# How to install SSL certificate to system-wide trust on SUSE

Tags: ssl-certificate, sles

I know this qualifies as one of the most asked questions in SF (and also possibly in SO), but (this time) I've done my homework:
I've read and tried [this](https://github.com/openSUSE/ca-certificates) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80131/how-do-i-install-a-system-wide-ssl-certificate-on-opensuse) without any luck.

So, I have my shiny new base-64 (cer) certificate singed by my corporate CA, now I need to add it to my server to be able to happily curl with SSL. I copy the file to /usr/share/pki/trust/anchors, make sure its 644 and owned by root. Then I run update-ca-certificates and I get nothing back (where in all the examples I've seen you're supposed to get a friendly message back confirming stuff).

I go sniff in /var/lib/ca-certificates and I dont see my certificate anywhere, neither under pem/ or in the ca-bundle.pem

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

So, first things first; I should not go sniffing around where I should not.
Behind the scenes update-ca-certs calls [trust](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/trust.1.html). So when I do a trust list I see my Cert there. What I was missing was adding the whole chain to my trust, so also the root and intermediate CAs. Once that was done curl was happy.